# What is the tension in the string of a spherical pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Can some one solve it by using Lagrange's undetermined multiplier method
or any other method that explains the physics in spherical pendulum system?
book references:
1) Classical mechanics by Goldstein, poole & Safko
2) Classical dynamics by J.B Marrian

Comment: Hi user34245, you haven't really asked a conceptual question here.  Can you reformulate your question to get at the heart of what concept you're asking about?  Right now this is a homework-like question and will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

We start from the Lagrangian in spherical coordinates

$$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^{2}+r^{2}\dot{\theta}^{2}+r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta\dot{\phi}^{2})+mgr\cos\theta$$

The length of the string is $d$ and the system is a constrained one with $|\vec{r}|=d$. Now, the constraint that is associated with a multiplier $\lambda$ is given by $c(r)=r-d=0$. At this point we have four equations and four unknowns (the three Lagrange equations and the constraint)

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{j}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{j}}=\lambda\frac{\partial c}{\partial q_{j}}$$

It is quite clear that only the equations for $r$ is involving the constraint $\lambda$.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial r}=\lambda\frac{\partial c(r)}{\partial r}$$

from which we find that

$$-md(\dot{\theta}^{2}+\dot{\phi}^{2}\sin^{2}\theta)-mg\cos\theta=\lambda$$

Here you have to be careful to see that the multiplier $\lambda$ is the force of constraint in the direction $\vec{e}_{r}$. Or in other words, the tension $T$, is equal to minus the force of constraint $T=-\lambda$. Thus

$$T=md(\dot{\theta}^{2}+\dot{\phi}^{2}\sin^{2}\theta)+mg\cos\theta$$

You can observe that if $\dot{\phi}=0$ (i.e. a planar pendulum) we stumble upon the familiar expression $T=md\dot{\theta}+mg\cos\theta$. Also, if $\theta\ll 1$ we get $T\simeq mg$, expression which is even more familiar. From the Lagrangian you can find the conserved quantities (hint: $L$ is independent of time, etc.) and get a feel for the physics. But you can start with something simpler. Choose units in which $m,g,d$ are all 1, such that the Lagrangian is reduced to

$$L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^{2}\theta\dot{\phi}^{2})+\cos\theta$$

I hope that with this simplified Lagrangian you can understand better the physics of a spherical pendulum.